# xampp, html files don't work in subfolders

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have a strange problem with xampp. I use:
xampp 1.8.3 - 
windows 7 64bit

On localhost, I can not open files .html in subfolders.

example:

`localhost/folder/*.html` = works. the page opens

`localhost/folder/subfolder/*.html` = doesn't work. Returns "object not found"

With *.php files no problem, they work in any folder. I looked at the configuration file httpd.conf

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
               default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html  default.htm \
               home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>
```

seems okay....

Comment: What you trying to do with that? Because this error **object not found** is a correctly error not a for example `HTTP 403`.

Comment: with *.html i mean any name .html ( index.html, page.html, form.html etc)